# How to Retrive the email field from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects

Actually I am trying to retrieve all the values of email field from array containing objects. But I couldn't able to do it. Please help me out.

```js
function User(name,email,pswd,repswd)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.email=email;
    this.pswd=pswd;
    this.repswd=repswd;
}
add();
 function add(){
            let myUserObj=new User(document.getElementById('name').value,document.getElementById('email').value,document.getElementById('pswd').value,document.getElementById('repswd').value);
           localStorage.setItem(document.getElementById("name").value,JSON.stringify(myUserObj));
           let myObj=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(document.getElementById("name").value));
           var arr=new Array();
           for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
             // console.log("User"+(i+1)+" "+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
              arr[i]=localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
             }
          console.log(arr);
          for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
          {
              for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
              {
                  console.log(arr[i]+"\n");
              }
         }
```

Firstly I took inputs from user and accessed it with constructor then I stored in local storage from it Stored to array. So what exactly i'm trying to do is to get all the values of email field from that array but i couldn't able to get it.

The output which i'm getting is below

(2) ["{"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@gmail.com","pswd":"Xyz@1234","repswd":"Xyz@1234"}", "{"name":"ritu","email":"ritu@gm.com","pswd":"Ritu1234","repswd":"Ritu1234"}"]

76 {"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@gmail.com","pswd":"Xyz@1234","repswd":"Xyz@1234"}

75 {"name":"ritu","email":"ritu@gm.com","pswd":"Ritu1234","repswd":"Ritu1234"}

please help me out to retrieve the email values.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `map`? I.e. `arr.map(obj => obj.email);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the emails just by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function User(name, email, pswd, repswd) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.pswd = pswd;
  this.repswd = repswd;
}

const arr = [
  new User('user1', 'user1@example.com', 'secret1', 'secret1'),
  new User('user2', 'user2@example.com', 'secret2', 'secret2'),
  new User('user3', 'user3@example.com', 'secret3', 'secret3'),
];

const emails = arr.map(user => user.email);

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Contribution. But actually the inputs are dynamic...I couldn't get the output through map. when i tried it i got output as undefined. Actually when a new user registers himself the User constructor has been called for assigning those particular values.